# How to assign the value of user control property to aspx or codebehind in VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webusercontrol

I have a user control with a public property which updates each time when a date from my calender(part of user control) is selected. Now I need to bring this value to page on which this user control is kept. How to do this.

I tried bringing the property value on page load event of aspx.vb(master page on which user control is present) but couldn't do it as page load is happening first and user property is loading next(null reference exception).

i tried this on page load of aspx `hdnPPSeq.Value = PPCalender1.test1.ToString`

Please share ideas to bring this value to aspx or codebehind in vb.

Comment: Implement a custom event with a meaningful name in your user-control which gets raised in the calender's SelectionChanged event. That event can be handled from the page. Read: [Mastering Page-UserControl Communication: Event Driven Communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3)

Comment: the calender is not regular calender it is a Iframe which is being used in many other areas of project,unfortunately cannot make changes to that. and I want to know how to bring the value of user control property to master page.

Comment: Don't use `Page_Load` to read the value of your UserControl but an event you've handled there("_which updates each time when a date from my calender is selected_"). Then raise a custom event which can be handled by the page.  I suspect you haven't read the link i've posted. Then you can pass the value either via event-parameter or via public property. I prefer a parameter since that does work even if you don't have direct access to the `UserControl`.

Comment: the update is happening from JavaScript which updates a hidden filed value which again is assigned to property. is there any way that I can catch this value from aspx page?

Comment: my scenario was different Tim, I figured it out. But, I learnt something new today...thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in usercontrol, which will return property value.

```
public partial class PassPropertyToPage : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    string strSelectDateTime;

    public string SelectedDateTime
    {
       set { strSelectDateTime = value; }
       get { return strSelectDateTime; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}

    public string GetDateTime()
    {    
      strSelectDateTime = <calendar value>;
      return strSelectDateTime;
    }   

}
```

And in page, call the method to get the value:

```
public partial class AccessUserControlProperty : System.Web.UI.Page
{     
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

       Response.Write("DateTime selected in page: " + PassPropertyToPage1.GetDateTime() + "<br/>");            
    }

}
```